# Function always return 0 value

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim price, dprice, total As Double

    total = price + dprice

    lstOutput.Items.Add("Cheese Cake : $ " & (FormatNumber(price, 2)))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Drink : $ " & (FormatNumber(dprice, 2)))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("===================")
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total : " & (FormatNumber(total, 2)))

End Sub

Function GetCakePrice(price As Double) As Double

    If chkChoco.Checked Then
        price += 2.0
    End If
    If chkBerry.Checked Then
        price += 2.5
    End If
    If chkBlack.Checked Then
        price += 3.0
    End If
    GetCakePrice = price
End Function

Function GetDrinkPrice(dprice As Double) As Double
    If radTea.Checked Then
        dprice += 1.8
    End If
    If radCoffee.Checked Then
        dprice += 2.0
    End If
    GetDrinkPrice = dprice
End Function
```

now the display shows both cheese cake and drink : $0 despite having their checkbox checked. tried tinkering around, please point out my mistake.

Comment: Where are you invoking your functions?

Comment: Are you using a debugger?

Comment: @BrianHooper im new to vb, what do you mean?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in my code, I didn't properly call my function didn't I?

Comment: In the code snippet you are creating variables `price`, `dprice` and `total` and printing them out. Nowhere are you actually setting them to anything; that'll be the reason they are zero.

Comment: @BrianHooper just as I suspected, how do I 'call' to use the function I've created and get them to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing invoking the functions you declared, and sending them parameters you don't need. I propose changes to of your code as follows:

**NOTE:** I'm supposing the first part of the code is another method, so I'll just call it Method().

```
Sub Method()
    Dim price, dprice, total As Double

    price = GetCakePrice()
    dprice = GetDrinkPrice()

    total = price + dprice

    lstOutput.Items.Add("Cheese Cake : $ " & (FormatNumber(price, 2)))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Drink : $ " & (FormatNumber(dprice, 2)))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("===================")
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Total : " & (FormatNumber(total, 2)))
End Sub

Function GetCakePrice() As Double
    If chkChoco.Checked Then
        price += 2.0
    End If
    If chkBerry.Checked Then
        price += 2.5
    End If
    If chkBlack.Checked Then
        price += 3.0
    End If
    GetCakePrice = price
End Function

Function GetDrinkPrice() As Double
    If radTea.Checked Then
        dprice += 1.8
    End If
    If radCoffee.Checked Then
        dprice += 2.0
    End If
    GetDrinkPrice = dprice
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are printing are not being set anywhere. To fill them in you need something like:-

```
price = GetCakePrice()  ' (The passed parameter serves no purpose here)
```

and the as the first line in the function declare a local working variable:-

```
Function GetCakePrice() As Double

    Dim price As Double

    If chkChoco.Checked Then
    .
    .
    etc
    .
```